# what will be the return read result from an atomic register

Tags: concurrency, language-agnostic, terminology, atomic

I have these 2 threads.

```
Thread 1:  wwwww
Thread 2:   rrrrr
```

The first write come from thread 1, and overlaps with the first read from thread 2.

There is an atomic register with the value 33 that will be accessed by both threads.
Thread1 write to the atomic register the value 68, and thread2 reads the value.

What will be the return result from thread2? 33 or 68?

Comment: It depends on whether the read happens before or after the write.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: The whole point of an "atomic" read/write is that it forces serialization.  So the results will depend on which thread "goes first". If the write happens first, the read will return the new value, else the old value.

If you have a single CPU, there can be no "overlap", as only one thread is running at a time.

If you have multiple CPUs, it will forcibly stall one CPU while it bounces the cache between the two CPUs. Only the "owner" of a cache line can write to it, and everybody else has to dump their (read-only) copy of the cache you write to it.

For the complex answer, you should read Ulrich Dreppers' fascinating article [What every programmer should know about memory](http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/).  Specifically, in section 3.3.4 of part 2, it describes the protocol where CPUs bounce caches around.  If you're dealing with Atomic memory access, you probably need good mental model of Memory. And Memory is far more complicated than you ever imagined.